# Remove Ads as a privilege for people that use many SE sites

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, privileges

I'm a member of many stack exchange sites and on some of the SE sites I have very little rep(about 110) where I have only asked or answered one question. And I find it annoying that the sites still have ads. I know they are needed to generate an income for the network. But they are annoying when browsing a site that you are not an expert nor a regular user of that SE. So would it be possible for users with accounts on multiple SE sites to have ads removed as well as having the privilege such that people with about 20 accounts and have used them once or twice will receive no ads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No Stack Exchange 2.0 network sites, except Stack Overflow and Server Fault (and sometimes Super User) show paid ads.

If you are referring to the one house ad in the sidebar, that "advertises"

- chat
- the site's meta
- interesting questions from other sites in the network
- the weekly site newsletter
- [community promotion ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) as determined by and voted on the site's meta

These are not paid ads and are required of every network site.

Answer (score 15):

I can't see the utility in this.

If you're active enough on the site to be bothered by the ads then it *should* be possible for you to get the extra 100 points of reputation you need not to see them (assuming you have the 100 point bonus from associating a 200+ account).

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what ChrisF reported, if you are active enough on an SE site to have a reputation of at least 200, then you would get 100 points bonus on all the SE sites where you use the same account. This means that, when you register a new account on a site where you didn't have an account, you start with a reputation of 101, if you use the same account you have in the site where your reputation is at least 200.

Comment: Thanks - that was implied in my answer!

Comment: I would call it "stage two": Get more involved, and you will never have again those limitations a user with a reputation lower than 100 has. :-)